# JavaFX : Use a Thread more than once

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx

I'm new with JavaFX and I've a little problem with a thread: I can execute it twice and I can't find why.

Here is a sum-upt of my code:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() throws ImageLoadedException, HomographyException, IOException {
        try{
            System.out.println("GO !");
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        super.succeeded();
        System.out.println("SUCCEEDED");
     }
};

@FXML protected void launch(ActionEvent event){
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

When I click a first time the button who start my thread, my task run without any problem (my console display "GO !" and "SUCCEEDED").

But if I click a second time, nothing append. Am I doing something wrong ? Can't we use a thread more than once ?

Comment: No, you cannot use a thread more than once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the  [Thread.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)  documentation : **No**

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

From the [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) tutorial :

> The Task class defines a one-time object that cannot be reused. If you
>   need a reusable Worker object, use the Service class.

So, you have to consider the [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) class rather than [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

---

**Edit**: this should work for you:

<strike>Service service = new Service<>(task);</strike>

```
//Updated use this to create a new Service object instead
    Service service = new Service() {
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //Your codes here
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};

@FXML protected void launch(ActionEvent event){
     if (!service.isRunning()) {
        service.reset();
        service.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to set the executor yourself and reuse that or you're still creating new threads everywhere.

Comment: @AndyTill can you suggest a better approach ?

Comment: Normally there would be a lot of service classes and resetting them would still leave one thread (executor) per service.  Reusing the Executor object by calling Service#setExecutor and creating a new instance of the service will allow you to reuse the threads created by that executor, if it is configured so.

Answer (score 1):

With a button can fire new tasks

```
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.setText("New task");
                    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                            Executor ex=new Executor("Task"+count);
                            ex.start();
                            count++;
                            System.out.println("Task  Starting...");
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a wraper class

```
            import java.io.IOException;
            import javafx.concurrent.Task;

            public class Executor {
                private String name;
                private Task<Void> task;

                public Executor(final String name) {
                    this.name=name;
                    task = new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void call() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                            try {
                                int i=0;
                                while(i<20){
                                    System.out.println(name);
                                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                                    i++;
                                }
                                return null;
                            } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void succeeded() {
                            super.succeeded();
                            try {
                                System.out.println(name+"  finish");
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }

                public void start() {
                    try {
                                Thread th = new Thread(task);
                                th.start();
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex);
                            }
                }
            }
```